# Adding a bunch of skus into a category using sql query

Tags: product, category

So I want to run a query that add a bunch of product using SKU number (comma separated) into a specific category ID number 21.

How do i do that? I know how to move them before category using this query. I like to know how to use the comma separated sku in the query, to move them into a category.

```
INSERT INTO 
    catalog_category_product( category_id, product_id, position ) 
    (
        SELECT 652 , product_id, position
        FROM catalog_category_product
        WHERE category_id IN ( 650 )
    )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE category_id = 652
```

Any help would be appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the query you are looking for is something along the lines like the one below.

I have taken it one step further and made sure that position is incremented and that you can choose the order in which you want the SKU's to show up.

```
SET @r = 0;

INSERT IGNORE INTO catalog_category_product (category_id, product_id, position)
SELECT 21, entity_id, @r:= (@r+1) FROM catalog_product_entity 
WHERE sku IN ('msj001', 'msj000') 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 'msj001', 'msj000');
```

Comment: So how do I ignore when there is duplicate entries in the category that i am inserting in? is there a query i can add on to this current query to tell it to ignore?

Comment: I have gone and adjusted the query so as to not fail on duplicate keys but rather ignore the duplicate and continue on.